# Plotly 3D scatterplot jittery and partially appearing with javascript

Tags: javascript, 3d, plotly, dataset, jitter

link for plot: https://codepen.io/Tpex/pen/YzOQNmV

```
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.18.2.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

```
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tpexas/dataset/main/csv.csv', function(err, rows){
      function unpack(rows, key) {
          return rows.map(function(row)
          { return row[key]; }); }

var x = unpack(rows , 'x');
var y = unpack(rows , 'y');
var z = unpack(rows , 'z');
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{
  type: 'scatter3d',
  mode: 'lines',
  x: x,
  y: y,
  z: z,
  opacity: 1,
  line: {
    width: 6,
    color: 3,
    reversescale: false
  }
}], {
  height: 640
});
});
```

The 3d plot is flashing/jittering while moving it and at some angles it doesnt show some dots at all

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tpexas/dataset/main/csv.csv
This dataset is taken from drone flight log, x represents latitude, y - longitude and z - altitude. Could it be that the differences between points are too small? Google maps api seems to generate normal 2D path with latitude and longitude.

Comment: *Could it be that the differences between points are too small?* - That, and the `mode: 'lines'` might be the reason why. I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23keo7dL/) with the mode changed to `circles`, and the scatterplot itself is not jittery (the axii are, though). Can you use a different CSV (randomly chosen coordinate values, which would not be so close apart), and try with that? **EDIT** [This](https://jsfiddle.net/23keo7dL/1/) is your current setup, but with the [official CSV](https://plotly.com/javascript/3d-scatter-plots/). Notice that there's no strange behaviour.

Comment: Ok so I tried to make another graph with bassically same csv except I removed firsts few digits from coordinates: 3821664733041, 75394602 instead of 32.3821664733041, -99.7539460179922 and this works perfectly even with lines [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gh4dtbk/2/). The problem with the cricle mode even though its not jittering that much but it is missing so many points. So I guess the coordinate points are too close...